# Number ticker to count up to value then stop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a number ticker which is a number field with a max value of 100.

With the current code below, my counter doesn't count. My guess is because in my demo, `data-count` is equal to the value, but I want the number to count up from 0.

I.e. If I change `data-count` to `100`, it will count up to 100 from 50, whereas I want it to count from 0 to it's value.

**Code**:

```js
$('.counter').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    countTo = $this.attr('data-count');

  $({
    countNum: $this.text()
  }).animate({
      countNum: countTo
    },

    {

      duration: 4000,
      easing: 'linear',
      step: function() {
        $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
      },
      complete: function() {
        $this.text(this.countNum);
        //alert('finished');
      }

    });

});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="numberTicker__list">

  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="numberTicker__content">
        <h3 class="counter" data-count="50">50</h3>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="numberTicker__content">
        <h3 class="counter" data-count="100">50</h3>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Try `countNum: 0` instead of `countNum: $this.text()`.

Answer (score 0):

Change code `countNum: $this.text()` to `Counter: 0`. It wil work.
Check below link for demo.

```js
$('.counter').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    countTo = $this.attr('data-count');

  $({
    Counter: 0
  }).animate({
      countNum: countTo
    },

    {
      duration: 4000,
      easing: 'linear',
      step: function() {
        $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
      },
      complete: function() {
        $this.text(this.countNum);
        //alert('finished');
      }

    });

});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="numberTicker__list">

  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="numberTicker__content">
        <h3 class="counter" data-count="50">50</h3>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="numberTicker__content">
        <h3 class="counter" data-count="100">50</h3>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:** The simplest way.

```js
$('.counter').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
      countTo = $this.attr('data-count'),
      countFrom = 0;

  $({
      countNum: countFrom
  }).animate({
      countNum: countTo
  },

  {

      duration: 4000,
      easing: 'linear',
      step: function() {
         $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
      },
      complete: function() {
         $this.text(this.countNum);
         //alert('finished');
      }

   });

});
```

```css
ul { list-style-type: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="numberTicker__list">

    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="numberTicker__content">
                <h3 class="counter" data-count="50">50</h3>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="numberTicker__content">
                <h3 class="counter" data-count="100">50</h3>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

**Solution 2:** The most appropriate way.

```js
$('.counter').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
      countFrom = $this.attr('data-countFrom'),
      countTo = $this.attr('data-countTo');

  $({
      countNum: countFrom
  }).animate({
      countNum: countTo
  },

  {

      duration: 4000,
      easing: 'linear',
      step: function() {
         $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
      },
      complete: function() {
         $this.text(this.countNum);
         //alert('finished');
      }

   });

});
```

```css
ul { list-style-type: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="numberTicker__list">

    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="numberTicker__content">
                <h3 class="counter" data-countFrom="0" data-countTo="50">50</h3>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="numberTicker__content">
                <h3 class="counter" data-countFrom="0" data-countTo="100">50</h3>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```